# Convert datepicker in Mysql Date - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all my goal is to convert the datepicker format into Date in mysql as I do:
my form :

```
$data_inizio = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['data_inizio']);
$data_fine = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['data_fine']);

<div class="md-form">
<!--The "from" Date Picker -->
<input name="data_inizio" placeholder="Data inizio" type="text" id="startingDate" class="form-control datepicker">
<label for="startingDate">Inizio</label>
</div>
<div class="md-form">
<!--The "to" Date Picker -->
<input name="data_fine" placeholder="Data Fine" type="text" id="endingDate" class="form-control datepicker">
<label for="endingDate">Fine</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL column is `DATE` type:

```
$data_inizio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data_inizio)));
$data_fine = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data_fine)));
```

If yout MYSQL column is DateTime type:

```
$data_inizio = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data_inizio)));
$data_fine = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $data_fine)));
```

Comment: strtotime() should be consigned to history and the http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php class used

Comment: Not Work, but i see when i "refresh" my db this: Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields. On submission, some of the fields might be ignored, due to PHP's max_input_vars configuration. But the fields are empty

Comment: Try this:

`$data_inizio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_inizio));
$data_fine = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data_fine));`

Comment: format: 'd mmmm, yyyy',
formatSubmit: undefined,
hiddenPrefix: undefined,
hiddenSuffix: '_submit',
hiddenName: undefined,